# Pytest: accessing a fixture from an outside function

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to know if there is a way to access a pytest fixture from functions located in other modules. I wonder if I could use  custom pytest hooks for this.

```
# test/test_file.py

pytest.fixture
def my_fixture()
   return my_object


def test_function():
    print('Starting test)
    my_function('arg1')
```

```
# lib/functions.py

def my_function(arg1):
    # I would like have access to my_fixture
```

So since it's possible to access fixtures in pytest hooks during runtime session, I wonder if there is a way to access them from outside of the test functions also.

So far this solution works for me:

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(self, item, call):
    # Stops at first non-None test result
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if rep.when == 'call' and hasattr(item, 'callspec'):
        test_case = item.callspec.params.get('test_case')
```

Here I can access `my_fixture` thingy, but only in a pre-defined hooks, pytest standard flow. I wonder if I could create my own hooks, and then make my functions "aware" of these and get the access to anything defined inside.

How to define and use custom hooks?

Comment: Can't you just move the fixture into a `conftest.py` that is found during test execution?

Comment: Hm. Maybe. How to do this @MrBeanBremen?

Comment: Well. put in somewhere into the test root - you are running these tests together, as I understand, and pytest is loading all `conftest.py` files it finds during test discovery. The location depends on your test layout, of course...

Comment: But I need different fixture for each test. Will it do the trick?

Comment: You can put as many fixtures in `conftest.py`, if that is what you are asking. Or do you mean you need different fixtures with the same name, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I need different fixtures with the same name.

Comment: But what is the connection between having these fixtures in conftest and accessing those in the "outside" code (functions). Could you shed some light on this concept?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215084/discussion-between-krzysztof-bober-and-mrbean-bremen).